# Is it Necessary to call my Trigger explicitily from my Test class to increase coverage?

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger functioning in Insert and Update Calls. Do I need to call the Trigger explicitly in my Test class to increase coverage?

Comment: Usually I would recommend to externalize the trigger logic into separate class and you can test that class directly. However, you still have to "invoke" trigger by making appropriate DML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot call trigger directly!!
You need to insert/update/delete/undelete your test record data to increase the coverage.

Basically you need to follow the step the way you will do it on UI level in the test class and it will automatically cover the code as per each scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You should a unit test for each trigger, but not to "increase coverage." The point of a unit test is to verify that your trigger is performing its business logic correctly, a check and balance system. Your triggers will most likely have coverage if any other of your unit tests insert or update records where the trigger resides, but this is not the same as explicitly verifying the trigger's logic. Each trigger should be tested through each possible branch to verify that the logic works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert test data in your test class. If triggers are written on the objects in context, they will automatically fire.

Comment: Not if they're update triggers. Nor delete/undelete.

Comment: If you have written trigger on contexts like "update" or "insert" or "delete" or "undelete" AND you do similar operation in your test class AND on the same object to that of trigger - THEN the trigger will fire. Now, what's valid or invalid inside a trigger would be a different question.

Comment: Your answer addresses none of that and hencehum is not very accurate or useful.

Comment: The answer was to the point and only related to the question in context. I am sure your understanding is quite different. If the question was seeking more, I would have definitely written more. Anyway, thanks for pointing out @Adrian Larson